# Input ref inside Popup is never acquired in Semantic UI React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, semantic-ui-react

I have simple popup in Semantic UI React that contains an input field. This input field should be focused immediately when the popup is opened. No luck so far. This is what I've tried:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Input, Label, Popup, Segment } from 'semantic-ui-react';

export class Test extends React.Component {
    private searchInput: React.RefObject<Input>;

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.searchInput = React.createRef();
    }

    public render() {
        return (
            <Popup
                trigger={<Label>Test</Label>}
                content={this.renderSelector()}
                on="hover"
                hoverable={true}
                position="bottom left"
                onOpen={() => this.focusInput()}
            />
        )
    }

    private renderSelector() {
        return (
            <Segment>
                <Input ref={this.searchInput} fluid={true} icon="search" iconPosition="left" />
            </Segment>
        )
    }

    private focusInput() {
        if (this.searchInput.current) {
            this.searchInput.current.focus()
        }
    }
}
```

`this.searchInput.current` is always null. I also tried to wrap the Input in a `Ref` component, but with the same result:

```
    private renderSelector() {
        return (
            <Segment>
                <Ref innerRef={this.searchInput}>
                    <Input fluid={true} icon="search" iconPosition="left" />
                </Ref>
            </Segment>
        )
    }
```

Finally, even when trying to find the Input in the DOM, I get a null result:

```
    private renderSelector() {
        return (
            <Segment>
                <Input id="foobar" fluid={true} icon="search" iconPosition="left" />
            </Segment>
        )
    }

    private focusInput() {
        const foo = document.getElementById("foobar");
        if (foo) {
            const bar = foo as HTMLInputElement;
            bar.focus();
        }
    }
```

Any idea what I am missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution, as answered here: https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/issues/3473

The main issue is basically that the ref is only available during the commit phase (which includes the componentDidUpdate method).

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Input, Label, Popup, Segment } from 'semantic-ui-react';

interface TestState {
    isOpen: boolean;
}

export class Test extends React.Component<{}, TestState> {
    private searchInput: React.RefObject<Input>;

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.searchInput = React.createRef();
        this.state = { isOpen: false };
    }

    public componentDidUpdate(prevProps: any, prevState: TestState) {
        if (!prevState.isOpen && this.state.isOpen) {
            if (this.searchInput.current) {
                this.searchInput.current.focus();
            }
        }
    }

    public render() {
        return (
            <Popup
                trigger={<Label>Test</Label>}
                content={this.renderSelector()}
                on="hover"
                hoverable={true}
                position="bottom left"
                onMount={() => this.setState({ isOpen: true })}
                onUnmount={() => this.setState({ isOpen: false })}
            />
        )
    }

    private renderSelector() {
        return (
            <Segment>
                <Input ref={this.searchInput} fluid={true} icon="search" iconPosition="left" />
            </Segment>
        )
    }
}
```